# How to send HTML form data to SQLite using Python

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite

So, last few days I was trying to build a website where you input the post data then hit submit and then boom your post appears on the home page/post page.

So, I have created the form but the problem is that I don't know how to send HTML form data to SQLite database so it can be viewed by multiple users anytime.

```html
<form class="posts" action="." method="post">
      
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
      
      <h2>Description</h2>
      <textarea input class="des" name="description"type="text" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
      
      <h2>Image(Optional)</h2>
      <input type="file" name="inpFile" id="inpFile" class="img-btn">
      
      <div class="img-prev" id="imgPrev">
        <img src="" alt="Image Preview" class="img-prev__img">
        <span class="img-prev__def-text">Image Preview</span>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

Comment: Can you share your Python code and HTML snippet so that people can understand what code is already present and what is remaining and help you bridge the gaps

Comment: here is the code for form that I used

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should take a look at some Python's web-frameworks like Flask or Django first, so that you can understand this subject a little clearer.

Comment: I don't want go in web-frameworks since my pc doesn't support frameworks well